# Python: Iterate over dict and list at the same time

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to write a function that can iterate over `dict` and `list` in the same way, like the following code. However, it does not work and blames that `iter` is not iterator.

```
def constructResult(*args):
    header = ''
    result = ''
    for arg in args :
        if isinstance(arg, dict) :
            iter = arg.items; #arg is a dict
        else:
            iter = arg #arg is a list 
        for (key,value) in iter :
            header = header + key + ","
```

Note: the inputs of this functions are either `dict` or `list`. This is an assumption.

Here is the error msg:

```
 File "./write-hole-collector.py", line 595, in constructResult
   for (key,value) in iter :
 TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Will the list also have two element tuples?

Comment: Aside: `iter` is the name of a handy [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#iter) and so not a good name for one of your own variables.

Comment: Yes It is. In fact, it was working when I had two functions to process list and dict separably.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to *call* the `dict.items()` method:

```
iter = arg.items()  #arg is a dict
```

otherwise you'll indeed get an exception telling you that the method itself isn't iterable:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for key, value in d.items:  # not called
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

That's because by not calling the method, you are trying to iterate over the method object, which doesn't support that operation.

Answer (score 1):

`for key in z.keys():
    print(key)`

Iterator over a function not variable. Instead of Keys try using keys()